# How can I replace or remove a special character in text with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to replace or remove this special character ">" from my text with Jquery.

ex. `<div class="test">></div>.`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just empty the text of the div.

```
$('div.test').text('');
```

or If you want to keep the other text intact, use like below.

```
var $div = $('div.test');
var str = $div.text(); 
$div.text(str.replace(/>/g, "")); //replaces all occurrences of > and assign again
```